# Adding three reference lines to a ggplot2 box plot works, but why can't I add two reference lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an example data frame:

```
#Libraries
library(tidyverse)

#Create example data 
ex <- data.frame(id = 1:300,
                 event = rep(c("f", "s", "t"), 100),
                 x = rnorm(300, 50, 20))
```

And I need to make one plot with three horizontal reference lines and one plot with two horizontal reference lines.

The plot with three horizontal reference lines works

```
##  Example Plot One (Three Reference Lines)  ##

#Create boxplot function
ex_triple_plot <- function(data){
  
  #Create datasets for references
  References <- data.frame( x = c(-Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf), 
                            y = c(60, 50, 40), 
                            References = factor(c(60, 50, 40), 
                                                labels = c("High",
                                                           "Medium",
                                                           "Low")))
  #Create Plots
  ggplot(data, aes(x = event, y = x)) + 
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
    geom_jitter(alpha=0.6) +
    geom_line(aes( x, y, color = References), References) +
    scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "red", "red"))}

#Plot
ex_triple_plot(ex)
```

But when I try to make a plot with two horizontal reference lines, the reference lines do not show up

```
##  Example Plot Two (Two Reference Lines)  ##

#Create boxplot function
ex_double_plot <- function(data){
  
  #Create datasets for references
  References <- data.frame( x = c(-Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf), 
                            y = c(60, 40), 
                            References = factor(c(60, 40), 
                                                labels = c("High",
                                                           "Low")))
  #Create Plots
  ggplot(data, aes(x = event, y = x)) + 
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
    geom_jitter(alpha=0.6) +
    geom_line(aes( x, y, color = References), References) +
    scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "red"))}

#Plot
ex_double_plot(ex)
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: second one should be `c(-Inf, -Inf, Inf, Inf)`

Comment: As rawr said, you the repetition/recycling of 2s and 3s messes up. An easier way to avoid the problem entirely would be to use `geom_hline` for horizontal lines, then you don't need the `Inf`s at all.

Comment: Both of these solutions work.  Thank you.